# How to add validation to not import existing record using ORACLE APEX data load wizard

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex-data-loader

I've added a data load page using the data load wizard in oracle apex. My problem is I just noticed that I can reupload the csv file that's been uploaded already (containing the same records), which causing for duplicate records.
How can I add a validation to not proceed the uploading once the data is already existing?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the simplest option is to create **unique index** which will prevent duplicates, i.e. Oracle will reject such rows itself.

If you want to make it "smarter", then you could create another table which contains file names you're uploading; then - after you choose which file you'll load - check whether that name already exists in table of previous imports and don't load it again.